# SAS - How to Count duplicates in SAS

Tags: count, sas, duplicates

I'm working on table in SAS and I'm getting my result as 70k lines + which is bit frustrating as I would like these to have only one output instead of 70k and counted of how many lines if possible.

My Code below:
`proc sql;`
`create table work.validations1 as select`
`a.LEASE_TYPE_DESC,`
`b.Lease_Type`
`from WORK.LIVE_FLEET_VA_STATUS_ASSETS a`
`left join WORK.DEFINITION_TABLE_1_0001 as b on a.LEASE_TYPE_DESC = b.Lease_Type`
`where b.Lease_Type = ''`
`;`

What should I add to that

Thank you in advance for any help.

I Tried using another line for Proc Data Sort however that didn't work out

Comment: I dont understand this. Do you simply want to know the number of duplicates?

Comment: @draycut I want to have one line instead of 70k duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of thinking about it I managed to find command on w3schools which solved my problem.

Instead of having `SELECT' I used` SELECT DISTINCT`